# Sqlite GROUP query

Tags: sqlite

I need to group result of test "PASS" / "FAIL" for serial number. If one or more Test "FAIL" the result for the serial number is "FAIL"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test
(
    Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Product TEXT NOT NULL,
    Serial INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Result TEXT NOT NULL,
    NTest INTEGER NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO Test (Product, Serial, Result,Ntest)
VALUES ('Sample', 1, 'PASS',1),('Sample', 1, 'FAIL',2),
('Sample', 1, 'PASS',3),('Sample', 2, 'PASS',1),
('Sample', 2, 'PASS',2),('Sample', 2, 'PASS',3);

SELECT Product,Serial,Result
FROM test
GROUP BY Serial;

DELETE FROM test;
DROP TABLE test;
```

I need this :

```
"Sample"    "1" "FAIL"
"Sample"    "2" "PASS"
```

but result are:

```
"Sample"    "1" "PASS"
"Sample"    "2" "PASS"
```

thanks

Comment: The serial are not unique, i have some kind of test for same serial and the result is "stored" like PASS or FAIL. Need to Group to have one row Product,Serial,Result. The result is PASS if all Rows for the same serial have PASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping results in a single output row for each group.
You cannot simply list a column that isn't grouped itself; it will just come from a random row in the group.

In this case, `'F'` < `'P'`, so you want the smallest value in the group:

```
SELECT Product, Serial, MIN(Result)
FROM test
GROUP BY Serial;
```